# Fibonacci Numbers Upper Bound

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Is it true that $F_n \le n^2 - 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? Certainly, it seems to work, at least for sufficiently small $m$. But I am having trouble proving this because (unfortunately) induction does not work, and I cannot think of a clever argument.

Any hints?

Comment: it's false. write out a few more Fibonacci numbers

Comment: It turns out that $F_{12} = 12^2$, so the first counterexample is really close.  But from there on the gap between your conjecture and the truth gets really big really fast.

Comment: it is wrong , you can check the problem again , but you try to write some more Fn numbers and you will see the problem is wrong

Answer (score 2):

From the  [expression for $\ F_n\ $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) in terms of the golden ratio $\ \varphi\ $ and its inverse, it follows that $\ F_n\sim\frac{\varphi^n}{\sqrt{5}}\ $.  Since $\ \varphi>1\ $ this grows faster than *any* polynomial in  $\ n\ $, let alone $\ n^2-1\!$.